# Prevent loss of timestamp when mapping over image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, composite

I am using the below code (taken from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321919/10-days-composite-from-sentinel-2-images-collection)) to make monthly composites of cloud masked S2 data but the reduce.median won't work because my ImageCollection doesn't have a timestamp. Does anyone know how I can add a timestamp to the masked ImageCollection?

```
/* Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}


var geometry = geometry; 

var col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
          .filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
          // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
          .map(maskS2clouds)

print(col)          

//Monthly Images
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2018,2018); 

// monthly composite
var monthlyImages =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var w = col.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2').filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
           //.mean()
           .median()
           //.min()
           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
  return w.set('year', y)
           .set('month', m)
           .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)) 

});
}).flatten());

print(monthlyImages)
```

Error: ImageCollection (Error)
reduce.median: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Certain (many) operations on an image will not include the image properties in the result. In your case, `divide(10000)` is the one dropping `system:time_start`. You can add all properties back with `copyProperties()`. First argument is the image or feature you want to copy properties from. By (the slightly annoying) default, all `system:*` properties is excluded. Provide a second argument to explicitly specify the list of property names to copy to include `system:*` properties. `image.propertyNames()` is the list of **all** property names.

```
image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/82b43cd41b05ba85292c907807009223